While install magento sample data throw error of data patch Magento 2?
I install the magento sample data in magento 2.4.7 and getting this kind of error

Error:: Unable to apply data patch
Magento\CatalogSampleData\Setup\Patch\Data\InstallCatalogSampleData
for module Magento_CatalogSampleData. Original exception message:
Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly.

can any one know how can I resolve it


This sometimes happens when the search engine is not configured correctly. For example, for 2.4.6 onwards, OpenSearch is used by default, if this is your case, make sure that this or ElasticSearch is set in the env.php file.
for example, this is what I have in my file (local environment)
'catalog' => [
    'search' => [
        'enable_eav_indexer' => '1',
        'engine' => 'opensearch',
        'opensearch_server_hostname' => 'opensearch',
        'opensearch_server_port' => '9200',
        'opensearch_index_prefix' => 'magento2',
        'opensearch_enable_auth' => '0',
        'opensearch_server_timeout' => '15'
    ]
],


I have seen several of these issues on my search for an answer to my errors like this one:
Unable to apply data patch Magento\BundleSampleData\Setup\Patch\Data\InstallBundleSampleData for ...
It turns out that whatever your version is, magento simply gives you the newest sample data which may or may not match at all. This is really stupid.
So say you have installed 2.4.7-p2 and you do
bin/magento sampledata:deploy
it will actually give you the version for 2.4.7-p3 ! and this may not match!
In my case I had installed 2.4.6-p2  and ran the bin/magento sampledata:deploy and .. error... and found this one:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37303
but it turns out, they install the newest (in their case it may be 2.4.6-p5) and then the sample data does so too. No error.
Really stupid. So. In case you for instance installed 2.4.7-p2 then:
first run bin/magento sampledata:remove !!!
then you should simply go to their https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data/releases/ and select that release (make sure the p-version matches too so in this case you would need magento2-sample-data-2.4.7-p2.tar.gz) and download this tar.gz file.
Put it in your Magento root and simply unpack it. Run setup:upgrade and there you go.

Seems that the issue might be related to the replace on composer that have (see https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.7-p2/composer.json#L318)
Try removing that line, composer update and try the commands again.
